# Why does docker report "no such file or directory": unknown?

Tags: java, docker

**what is expected**

docker should build the image and run the container out of it

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:7

ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u191
ENV BUILD_VERSION b12

RUN yum -y install wget; wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/$JAVA_VERSION-$BUILD_VERSION/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-$JAVA_VERSION-linux-x64.rpm" -O /tmp/jdk-8-linux-x64.rpm; yum -y install /tmp/jdk-8-linux-x64.rpm

# JDK stripping
RUN rm -f /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/src.zip /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/javafx-src.zip
RUN rm -rf /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/lib/missioncontrol/ /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/lib/visualvm/ /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77/db/

RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/bin/java 1
RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/latest/bin/javac 1

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/java/latest
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/latest/bin/java
RUN echo "$PATH"

RUN rm -f /tmp/jdk-8-linux-x64.rpm; yum -y remove wget; yum -y clean all

COPY target/gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar /tmp/gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar

CMD [ "java -jar /tmp/gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar" ]
```

build-context is the current directory where Dockerfile resides. following is the directory structure

```
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root     root     1079 Oct 29 03:42 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1917 Oct 27 09:17 pom.xml
drwxrwxr-x. 4 ec2-user ec2-user   30 Oct 27 10:15 src
drwxr-xr-x. 9 root     root      261 Oct 27 10:19 target
```

i am executing following command to build the image :

```
docker build --no-cache -f Dockerfile -t cpa:latest .
```

but when running the container , getting following message

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8081/tcp cpa   
b2ba9831f1b74c73669843658727ca0d64fcd9de915739b96e17dcfd6e63c7db
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"java -jar /tmp/gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar\": stat java -jar /tmp/gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

I am not sure why the built jar is not available in the /tmp dir of the container file system 
in the docker documentation `COPY`
is the right keyword to be used to copy files from host machine to container file system ... 
but then where is the issue ..?
please suggest

EDIT 1 : fixed the type mistake from 77 to 191 
here is the latest Dockerfile....

```
FROM centos:7

ENV JAVA_VERSION 8u191
ENV BUILD_VERSION b12

RUN yum -y install wget; wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/$JAVA_VERSION-$BUILD_VERSION/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-$JAVA_VERSION-linux-x64.rpm" -O /tmp/jdk-8-linux-x64.rpm; yum -y install /tmp/jdk-8-linux-x64.rpm

# JDK stripping
RUN rm -f /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191/src.zip /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191/javafx-src.zip
RUN rm -rf /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191/lib/missioncontrol/ /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191/lib/visualvm/ /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191/db/

RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/bin/java 1
RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/latest/bin/javac 1

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/java/latest
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/latest/bin/java
RUN echo "$PATH"

RUN rm -f /tmp/jdk-8-linux-x64.rpm; yum -y remove wget; yum -y clean all

COPY target/gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar /tmp/gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar

CMD [ "java -jar /tmp/gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar" ]
```

further, the `target` dir is part of the build context 
please refer below:

```
[root@ip-172-31-14-242 cpa_final]# pwd
/tmp/cpa_final
[root@ip-172-31-14-242 cpa_final]# ll
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root     root     1084 Oct 29 05:16 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1917 Oct 27 09:17 pom.xml
drwxrwxr-x. 4 ec2-user ec2-user   30 Oct 27 10:15 src
drwxr-xr-x. 9 root     root      261 Oct 27 10:19 target
[root@ip-172-31-14-242 cpa_final]# cd target/
[root@ip-172-31-14-242 target]# ll
total 17304
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root       36 Oct 27 10:18 classes
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root       25 Oct 27 10:18 generated-sources
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root       30 Oct 27 10:18 generated-test-sources
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 17708542 Oct 27 10:19 gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     4858 Oct 27 10:18 gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar.original
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       28 Oct 27 10:18 maven-archiver
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root       35 Oct 27 10:18 maven-status
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root      121 Oct 27 10:18 surefire-reports
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root       19 Oct 27 10:18 test-classes
[root@ip-172-31-14-242 target]#
```

EDIT 2:

the mentioned jar file is there in `/tmp` dir of the container file system. PSB

```
[root@ip-172-31-14-242 ~]# docker run -it cpa /bin/bash
[root@4018a6c2df8e /]# cd /tmp
[root@4018a6c2df8e tmp]# ll
total 17300
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 17708542 Oct 27 10:19 gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar
-rwx------. 1 root root      836 Oct  6 19:15 ks-script-7RxiSx
-rw-------. 1 root root        0 Oct  6 19:14 yum.log
[root@4018a6c2df8e tmp]#
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/latest/bin/java
```

should probably be

```
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/latest/bin
```

I assume what is not being found is the java executable. Please check that java is really on the PATH.

What is ALSO wrong is this line:

```
CMD [ "java -jar /tmp/gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar" ]
```

This should read:

```
CMD [ "java", "-jar", "/tmp/gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar" ]
```

Right now it is looking for a file called
"java -jar /tmp/gs-handling-form-submission-0.1.0.jar" and tries to execute that.

Answer (score 8):

The CMD command has three forms. Each of them can do the job for you.

- `CMD ["param1","param2"]`: "*parameter*" form
- `CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]`: "*exec*" form
- `CMD command param1 param2`: "*shell*" form

The first two look the same but their meaning depends on whether there is an `ENTRYPOINT` in the `Dockerfile` or not.

1. The *parameter* form is used when you have an `ENTRYPOINT` in your `Dockerfile`. In this case, the strings from the CMD command are the arguments of the executable defined in the `ENTRYPOINT`. In your case:

   ```
   ENTRYPOINT ["/<path-to-your-java-binary>/java"]
   CMD ["-jar", "myjar.jar"]
   ```

   NB. The parameters listed in `CMD` must be different strings. `CMD ["a", "b"]` means you pass two arguments to the command while `CMD ["a b"]` means only one parameter.
2. The *exec* form is used if there is no `ENTRYPOINT` in the `Dockerfile`. In this case, the first string is the command and the subsequent ones are the individual arguments. In your case:

   ```
   CMD ["/<path-to-your-java-binary>/java", "-jar", "myjar.jar"]
   ```

   Be aware of that in the *exec* form there is no shell processing, ie. shell variables are not defined.
3. In the *shell* form, however, you have access the shell variables and the first argument (`command`) will be executed by the shell `/bin/sh` with the given parameters. In your case:

   ```
   CMD /<path-to-your-java-binary>/java -jar myjar.jar
   ```

Take-away: the simplest is the best in this case.

Answer (score 2):

For me below change worked that is changing from

```
CMD ["java -jar myjar.jar"]
```

to

```
CMD java -jar myjar.jar
```

Try removing square brackets and double quotes

Comment: The same seems to work for ENTRYPOINT